# Specifying package build order with Ament

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to make Ament build packages in a specific order? I have a package set up similar to how the Common Interfaces package is set up in Ardent (like a metapackage) and the packages get built in alphabetical order by default. I am trying to resolve dependency issues with the packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287559/specifying-package-build-order-with-ament/) by [Dan.K](https://answers.ros.org/users/26460/dan.k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ament will build things in dependency order. You should make sure to declare the dependencies and then it will build them in the right order. Alphabetical order is just used as a deterministic tie breaker.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0